# Handling back-key in custom view of a dialog

Tags: java, android

Okay so I have a custom view inside a dialog but its onKeyDown never get called. I tried onKeyPreIme too but didn't work and setting dialog's setCancelable to true didn't help either.

edit :

```
//Removed all unnecessary code

public class CustomView extends LinearLayout
{    

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
            {           
                   //do stuff here
                    return true;

            }    
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);         
    }
}
public class CustomDialog
{
    Dialog dialog;
    public class CustomDialog(Context context)
    {
         dialog = new Dialog(context);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);// the test.xml has CustomView

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the functionality that you desire? Post some code please. It isn't clear what your code does from your words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `onKeyDown` logics  to an `OnKeyListener` implementation and register it in your View's constructor.

Comment: Okay had to to use KeyListener of Dialog and it gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
       //desired functionality here 
       return;
    }
```

Comment: if I'm not wrong, it works inside an Activity, not inside a View. Besides I'm using Android 1.6, it doesn't have that event.

Comment: Otherwise do as mentioned in the other answer, use a `onKeyListener` for your `onKeyDown`.

Comment: its a library project, of course it will be used for an activity. What you are saying, is a trick, which will be done every time someone uses the library.